# Advantage of #define instead of creating a function in embedded

Tags: c, embedded

Recently I got to view an embedded code in that they are using

```
#define print() printf("hello world")
```

instead of

```
void print() { printf("hello world"); }
```

My question what is the gain on using `#define` instead of creating a function?

Comment: Is `static inline void print(void) { printf(“hello world”); }` an option. It is probably the best choice if you can use it.  That probably applies even more when you use a less minimal function/macro — one that takes arguments etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may be related to performance.

A function call has some overhead (i.e. calling, saving things on the stack, returning, etc) while a macro is a direct substitution of the macro name with it's contents (i.e. no overhead).

In this example the functions `foo` and `bar` does exactly the same. `foo` uses a macro while `bar` uses a function call.

[image]

As you can see `bar` and `printY` together requires more instructions than `foo`
.

So by using a macro the performance got a little better.

But... there are downsides to this approach:

- Macros are hard to debug as you can't single step a macro
- Extensive use of a macro increases the size of the binary (compared to using function call). Something that can impact performance in a negative direction.

Also notice that modern compilers (with optimization on) are really good at figuring out when it's a good idea to automatically inline a function (i.e. your code is written with a function call but the compiler decides to inline the function as if it was a macro). So you might get the same performance using function call.

Further, you can use the `inline` key word as a hint to the compiler that you think it will be good to inline a function. But even with that keyword the compiler may decide not to inline. The only way to make sure that the code gets inline, is by using a macro.

Comment: Depending on the age of the code in question, it is more likely for code size, not speed.  As doron points out below, a macro makes it trivial to excise unwanted code in the final production image.  Back in the bad old days (and today, if you are still living in 8-bit processor land) this was extremely common for selective debugging.

Answer (score 5):

There is no advantage. Using `#define` like this is quite ancient C programming style.

In the year 1999, the C language got the `inline` keyword to make all such macros obsolete. And with modern compilers, `inline` is often superfluous too, since the compiler is nowadays better than the programmer when it comes to determining when to inline.

Some of the embedded compilers out can still be rather bad at such optimizations though, and that's why embedded C code tends to lag behind in modernization.

In general, doing micro-optimizations like this is called "pre-mature optimizations", meaning the programmer is meddling with optimizations that they should leave to the compiler. Even in hard real time systems. Optimizations should only be the last resort when you have 1) detected an actual bottleneck, and 2) disassembled to see if manual inlining actually does anything good for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you want to stub out functionality at compile time. Macros give you an easy way to do this.

Comment: This doesn't look like a stub, but just some example the OP cooked up.

Comment: You might want the print to happen in the debug version, and have it be omitted from the release version by `#define print()   ` (an empty definition).

Comment: I need to set Some of the register values. To enable uart or something like that.